# Hive variables usage

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm using hive 0.9.0 version on Cloudera-Training-VM-4.1.1.c.
I’m facing issue in using hive variable in the `SELECT` query. Please have a look and let me know where I’m going wrong.

1)  This is my table named `rushi_target`

```
hive> desc rushi_target;
OK
load_ts         timestamp   
id       int      
name string 
loc     string 
data_dt        string 
Time taken: 0.154 seconds
```

2) This is the data

```
hive> select * from rushi_target;
OK
2015-12-01 00:02:34 1        rushi  pune  2015-12-01
2015-12-02 04:02:34 2        komal pune  2015-12-02
2015-12-03 00:03:34 3        bhanu bangalore     2015-12-03
2015-12-04 00:03:34 4        sachin          pune  2015-12-04
Time taken: 0.258 seconds
```

3) setting hive variable

```
hive> set maxtimevar= select max(load_ts) from rushi_target;
```

4) displaying the value of hive variable

```
hive> ${hiveconf:maxtimevar};
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_201512211113_0011, Tracking URL = http://0.0.0.0:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201512211113_0011
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=0.0.0.0:8021 -kill job_201512211113_0011
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2015-12-22 08:51:35,401 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-12-22 08:51:37,409 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 0.83 sec
2015-12-22 08:51:38,416 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 0.83 sec
2015-12-22 08:51:39,423 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 1.43 sec
2015-12-22 08:51:40,429 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 1.43 sec
2015-12-22 08:51:41,439 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 1.43 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 1 seconds 430 msec
Ended Job = job_201512211113_0011
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 1.43 sec   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 seconds 430 msec
OK
2015-12-04 00:03:34
Time taken: 8.632 seconds
```

5) Why is this not working?

```
hive> select * from rushi_target where load_ts= ${hiveconf:maxtimevar};
FAILED: ParseException line 1:42 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification
```

6) This doesn't throw any error but gives no output as well:

```
hive> select * from rushi_target where load_ts = '${hiveconf:maxtimevar}';
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201512211113_0025, Tracking URL = http://0.0.0.0:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201512211113_0025
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=0.0.0.0:8021 -kill job_201512211113_0025
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2015-12-22 10:16:56,666 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-12-22 10:16:58,675 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 0.39 sec
2015-12-22 10:16:59,686 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 0.39 sec
2015-12-22 10:17:00,696 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 0.39 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 390 msec
Ended Job = job_201512211113_0025
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 0.39 sec   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 390 msec
OK
Time taken: 6.568 seconds
hive>
```

I want to use the hive variable `maxtimevar` in `SELECT` query. Please suggest how to use.

Comment: Please format the question. Hardly readable.

Comment: Thanks Damian for formatting

Answer (score 0):

Hive variables usage is to pass values not queries.

Your query `select * from rushi_target where load_ts = '${hiveconf:maxtimevar}';` is evaluating to `select * from rushi_target where load_ts = 'select max(load_ts) from rushi_target'`. It is looking for data with load_ts as the query and obviously there will be no data with those values.

This one from 5, `select * from rushi_target where load_ts= ${hiveconf:maxtimevar};` will be evaluated to `select * from rushi_target where load_ts= select max(load_ts) from rushi_target;`. This is not valid query and hence it is failing with syntax errors.

You need to write the query like this.

```
select rt.* from rushi_target rt 
join 
(select max(load_ts) max_load_ts from rushi_target) rt1 
on 1=1 
where rt.load_ts = rt1.max_load_ts;
```

Comment: Its working for small set of data on my local desktop. But not working when applied to millions of records. Getting stuck in between. Will post the new question.

Comment: posted my next question based on this scenario. I upvoted you. Is it getting reflected?

Comment: No, it is not yet reflecting. That is fine, I think you need to have enough score to do so.

Comment: the above query will introduce cross join. while it will not affect performance on small set of data, but on a huge dataset this will show considerable issues.